# Excel: Get index of THIS cell - 1

Tags: excel, indexing, sum

I've built a php tool which grabs data from a database and creates an excel sheet like this.

[image]

I want to sum up all durations. I cant use "=SUM(F2:F7)" in F8 because every new sheet has a different amount of rows.

I need something like this in F8: "=SUM(F2:INDEX.OF.THIS.CELL-1)"

Thanks.

Comment: In your `php` tool, can you not do a count on the records returned? This would allow you to `F2:F` & `count+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("F2:F" & ROW()-1))
```